# Scraping table data from a Wikipedia page

Tags: python, html

I am learning how to use the BeautifulSoup library with Python and for practice I am trying to strip the genre titles from this Wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jazz_genres

I have been able to get this far in my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = open("wiki-jazz.html", encoding="utf=8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all("table")[1]
td = table.find_all("td")
print(td)
```

table[1] contains the data that I want to access. More specifically, I really just need the data located within this title attributes:

```
</td>, <td><a href="/wiki/West_Coast_jazz" title="West Coast jazz">West Coast jazz</a>
```

I have been wracking my brain on how to extract this information. I have looked at other posts on here but can't quite get there.
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the first column of the table, you can iterate over the rows (`<tr>`) and then get all cells of row (`<td>`). First cell in each row is your jazz genre:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jazz_genres'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all("table")[1]

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:    # <-- [1:] because we don't want the header
    cells = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all('td')]
    print(cells[0])
```

Prints:

```
Acid jazz
Afro-Cuban jazz
Avant-garde jazz
Bebop
Bossa nova
British dance band
Cape jazz
Chamber jazz
Continental jazz
Cool jazz
Crossover jazz
Dark jazz/Doomjazz[1][2][3]
Dixieland
Electro Swing
Ethio jazz
Ethno jazz
European free jazz
Free funk
Free jazz
Frevo
Gypsy jazz
Hard bop
Hot club
Indo jazz
Jazz blues
Jazz-funk
Jazz fusion
Jazz rap
Jazz rock
Kansas City blues
Kansas City jazz
Latin jazz
M-Base
Mainstream jazz
Modal jazz
Neo-bop jazz
Neo-swing
Neo-bop jazz
Novelty ragtime
Nu jazz
Orchestral jazz
Post-bop
Punk jazz
Ragtime
Ska jazz
Smooth jazz
Soul jazz
Straight-ahead jazz
Stride jazz
Swing
Third stream
Trad jazz
Vocal jazz
West Coast jazz
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. With the cells line, you created a list, correct? If that is the case, how it cells[0] not just printing the first index value? I am going to study this code.

Comment: @Connor Yes, `cells = [...]` is called _list-comprehension_ and it creates new list. To get first value from this list, just call `cells[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You should read Beautifulsoup documentation about how to get attributes within tag like href src etc

Here you can use

```
item[1].get(‘title’)
```